# Solving quadratic equation in two variables

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

How do I solve equations like
$$kx = 9k^2 +4k+4$$

I can solve for $x$ but am unable to do it for $k$.
Anyone can explain it to me?

Comment: you can write it as $9k^2+(4-x)k+4=0$ and then solve for $k$.

Comment: If you knew the value of $x$, would yoube able to solve for $k$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$9k^2+(4−x)k+4=0$$
$$D=(4-x)^2-4\cdot 9 \cdot 4=16-8x+x^2-144=x^2-8x-128$$
$$k_{1,2}=\frac{x-4 \pm \sqrt{x^2-8x-128}}{18}$$
real solutions exist when $x^2-8x-128\ge 0$ ($x \in (-\infty; -8]\cup[16;\infty)$)

Comment: precising for which $x$ the discriminant is positive would be nice.